# ngRoute check if route is valid

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am using angular-route for the routing in my app.

I am generating some links, and I would like to check to make sure the link has been defined in routeProvider, and won't go to the 404 page.

Is there any way using ngRoute to determine if a route will resolve correctly?

I have considered using $route.routes and writing something to manually check for my route, but I would prefer to use something built-in to ngRoute.

Comment: Could you post your attempt?

Comment: I haven't actually attempted anything yet - I was hoping that there was something built into ngRoute that could do this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in to ngRoute that allows you to do this.

Checking $route.routes is your best bet, a simple filter on it's contents will do.

Comment: That's what I figured - if no one else knows anything more I'll do exactly that. Thank you!